# how can i implement this concept using mysql?

Tags: mysql

My aim is to make a procedure that take a text -may contain idioms- as an input and it is output should be that text after replacing each idiom with it's meaning that their is a table called "idioms" which has two columns : the first is for idiom called "idiom" and the second is for idiom meaning and called "idiomMeaning" and this is my work till now :

```
delimiter //
create procedure idioms_search (in input text, out output text )

begin

   WHILE EXISTS (SELECT idiom  FROM idioms  WHERE input LIKE CONCAT('%',@idiom,'%');)  

       SELECT REPLACE (@input,@idiom,@idiomMeaning ) INTO output;

end while;

end

//

delimiter ;
```

but the previous code contain errors , Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop called while exists in mysql. The loop is coded like the example given below

```
while x<=5 do
select x;
end while;`
```

try and use cursors. Rephrase your select statement as given below and try

```
SELECT idiom  FROM idioms  WHERE idiom like concat('%',input,'%');
```

Comment: exists+select statement = condition
that i tried to use this condition with if statement and it works fine

Comment: exists keyword can be used with if but not with while.

Comment: Is no one here could help me ?